# How to continuously check collisions in Tiled tilemaps during a CCMoveTo

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hello good people of stack overflow
I stand before you today with a (not very great) cocos2d issue.

How can I check collisions WHILE in an action, instead of checking the target tile?
I am working with a tilemap that has a meta layer where there are collidable tiles. The following code works when I click the collidable tile, but not when I click beyond it, if that happens he will just walk straight through.

Currently, I detect collisions with this code:

```
-(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:position];
int tileGid = [_meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
if (tileGid) {
    NSDictionary *properties = [_tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
    if (properties) {
        NSString *collision = properties[@"Collidable"];
        if (collision && [collision isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

float speed = 10;
CGPoint currentPlayerPos = _player.position;
CGPoint newPlayerPos = position;
double PlayerPosDifference = ccpDistance(currentPlayerPos, newPlayerPos) / 24;
int timeToMoveToNewPostition = PlayerPosDifference / speed;
id moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:timeToMoveToNewPostition position:position];
[_player runAction:moveTo];

//_player.position = position;
}
```

By the way, this gets called from this method:

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[_player stopAllActions];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;
CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);

int diffx = diff.x;
int diffy = diff.y;
int adiffx = diffx / 24;
int adiffy = diffy / 24; //Porque my tile size is 24     

if ( abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y) ) {
    if (diff.x > 0) {
        playerPos.x = playerPos.x + adiffx * 24;
    } else {
        playerPos.x = playerPos.x + adiffx * 24;
    }
} else {
    if (diff.y > 0) {
        playerPos.y = playerPos.y + adiffy * 24;
    }else{
        playerPos.y = playerPos.y + adiffy * 24;
    }
}
[self setPlayerPosition:playerPos];
}
```

I tried

```
    [self schedule:@selector(setPlayerPosition:) interval:0.5];
```

Without any luck, that just instantly crashed the app at this

`NSAssert( pos.x < _layerSize.width && pos.y < _layerSize.height && pos.x >=0 && pos.y >=0, @"TMXLayer: invalid position");`
And i can't really blame it for crashing there.

How do I constantly check for collisions with the collidable meta tiles while a `CCMoveTo` is running?

Comment: You're only checking the tile at the position of the touch. Do you maintain an array of all tiles? If so, then you could schedule a "collision detector" method that is actively checking any collisions between the player and all tiles.

Comment: No I dont, because I dont know how :D Can you enlighten me, great @SmugbitStudios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your init, schedule a collision detecting method:

```
[self schedule:@selector(checkCollisions:)];
```

Then define it as follows:

```
-(void)checkCollisions:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGPoint currentPlayerPos = _player.position;
    CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:currentPlayerPos];
    int tileGid = [_meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
    if (tileGid) 
    {
        NSDictionary *properties = [_tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
        if (properties) 
        {
            NSString *collision = properties[@"Collidable"];
            if (collision && [collision isEqualToString:@"True"]) 
            {
                [_player stopAllActions];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This (kinda) works! Except, he gets stuck inside tiles when he collides into them.. Like halfway into. Any method to just make him unable to walk when there is something in his way?

Comment: doing it this way only stops the sprite once they are inside the wall.

Comment: you should be checking collision before you move, and stop the move if the move would put you inside a wall.

Comment: The player position is relative to the anchorPoint. By default, it is ccp(0.5f, 0.5f), which is right in the middle of the player sprite. You can keep track of the direction of the player (up,down,left,right), and modify currentPlayerPos accordingly (up would need to add half the player's height, down would need to subtract it, left would need to subtract half the player's width, and right would need to add it).

Comment: so basically you would be able to squeeze through any one pixel crevas. this would be okay I guess if you can only move in four directions. once you add diagonal movement however, this method will fail, because you will be able to go through two diagonally adjacent collidable tiles.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that it does not look right if you can move parallel to a collidable tile only one pixel away from your anchor point, but when you walk directly at the collidable tile, you can only get within 16 pixels from your anchor point.

Comment: Given the use of CCMoveTo, I assumed the idea was to move the player to the touch position, and if any obstacle got in the way, it would move to the tile closest and then stop. If you also wish to move diagonally, only 4 more directions are required (NE, SE, NW, SW), and the tile position checked could be modified as well. I also think it would handle 1 pixel boundaries fine, but given that the other code suggests whole-tile movement, the minimum is 24 pixels, the width of a single tile.

Comment: @SmugbitStudios Sorry for the slow reply. You are correct, I only want NE SE NW SW walking, and stopping at the tile before it crashes.

Answer (score -1):

I using a similar meta layer. I personally skipped using MoveTo, and created my own update code that both moves the sprite and does collision detection.

I figure out what the potential new position would be, then I find out what tile position is in all four corners of the sprite at that new position, then I cycle through all tiles that the sprite would be on and if any are collidable, I stop the sprite.

I actually go a step further and check if moving only the x, or only the y changes the results, then move to that position instead if it does.

Comment: This seems smart, but i'm not really at the level to implement my own CCMoveTo methods.. Can you provide an example / explain a bit more indepth on how to start out?

Comment: I keep it simple, but use one complex math equation. Instead of saying move to foo position, I say move in direction foo, with a speed of bar. I then use math to figure out what the next frames position would be based on the direction and speed. Once I know what the new position would be, I can check the stuff mentioned above. Also, to limit this movement, I say move in foo direction, at a speed of bar, with a duration of baz. I then keep track of the total ellapsed time, and stop movement once the set duration is over.

Comment: Seems like a smart way. Would you be interested in posting your code? Please :D